# what does -prune -o -type f -print mean in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am writing a shell script and I want to ignore a certain directory, and input into a temporary file. I want to find all the files, while ignoring a certain path.

Can someone explain what the below code means?

```
find . -path ./.git -prune -o -type f -print | sort > ${temporaryfile1}
```

Not sure what it means. Just trying to understand.

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

Comment: `-prune` forbids descending below the found file/directory -- You can also run a `man find` and read what the flags do there ..

Comment: `-prune -o -type f -print` doesn't mean anything to bash. Those are arguments to the command `find`, not `bash`

Comment: Per the manual: -prune True; if the file is a directory, do not descend into it.  If -depth is given, then -prune has no effect.  Because -delete implies -depth,
              you cannot usefully use -prune and -delete together.
                For example, to skip the directory `src/emacs' and all files and directories under it, and print the names of the other files found,  do
              something like this:
                        find . -path ./src/emacs -prune -o -print

Comment: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find+.+-path+.%2F.git+-prune+-o+-type+f+-print+%7C+sort+%3E+%24%7Btemporaryfile1%7D

Answer (score 1):

This is a `find` command that searches for files in the current directory and its subdirectories. Let's break it down step by step:

1. `find .`: This starts the `find` command and tells it to search from the current directory (represented by `.`) and its subdirectories.
2. `-path ./.git`: This matches any path that is equivalent to `./.git` or anything inside this directory.
3. `-prune`: This tells `find` to not descend into the current file/directory. So if it encounters a directory that matches the `-path ./.git` expression, it won't look inside that directory. Essentially, this skips searching inside the `.git` directory.
4. `-o`: This stands for "OR". The way `find` processes this is it will execute the action of the preceding expression (i.e., `-prune` for the `.git` directory) OR the action of the following expression.
5. `-type f`: This matches only regular files (not directories, links, etc.).
6. `-print`: This tells `find` to print the path of the file to the standard output.

Putting it all together:

- The command first looks for the `.git` directory. When it finds it, it skips looking inside it.
- For all other paths, if they are regular files, the command prints their paths.
- It does not print paths of directories (other than `.git`) since the `-print` action is only specified for regular files.

Finally:

`| sort > ${temporaryfile1}`: This takes the output of the `find` command, sorts it alphabetically (`sort`), and then redirects the sorted list of file paths to a file specified by the variable `temporaryfile1`.

So, in summary, the command finds all regular files in the current directory and its subdirectories (excluding anything inside the `.git` directory), sorts them, and saves the sorted list in a temporary file.

Answer (score 1):

To break each part down:

```
find .              # start at the current directory
     -path ./.git      # if the path matches ./.git ...
        -prune            # Then discard anything below it
     -o                # otherwise, for things that did not have that path
        -type f           # if this is a "normal" file
           -print            # then print its path
| sort              # Sort the things that were printed
> ${temporaryfile1} # And output to the given filename
```

Things that fail both the `-path` and `-type` tests will be ignored. By default, `find` adds an implicit `-print` operation (so `find .` is the same as `find . -print`), but if you include an operation (like `-print`), then paths that fail all the tests are ignored.